# how to proceed to create a website using Java

Tags: java, html, web

I know this question sound weird to some folks but I am very confused about how should I start to create a website. I know Java, HTML5 and having some idea about CSS and Javascript also. Please help me about what steps should I take care of?
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try taking a look at something like the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, if you're not yet very comfortable with Java, I would suggest picking up a good Java book (like Thinking in Java - [the 3rd Edition is free online, and is a good place to start!](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)) - IMHO it's better to use a proper (and up to date) book to get started, then just googling tutorials and learning from them.

Secondly, if you are already comfortable with Java, you should look into Servlets and how they run. You need to set up a server (usually on your localhost) and run your Java web application on that server for learning and testing purposes. One such server is Tomcat, and it's very easy to get started with it (assuming you're on Windows) by installing the [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) bundle. Later, if you're still interesting, it's rather important that you start using a web application framework such as the well-known [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) - it lightens the overall workload tremendously.

Later you can use a service such as [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) to publish your website and make it available on the internet.

Just remember to take it one step at a time! If you rush into too many things at once (like, for instance, attempting this project with shaky knowledge of both Java and HTML) things can get really confusing, really fast. Trust me, it's happened to me plenty of times!

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I will take care of everything whatever u mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The most fundamental technologies are JSPs and Servlets.  But, you'll need a web server to compile them into HTML.  [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a very popular web server.  You want to learn more about Web Frameworks.  I recommend [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/Home)